# Elimante render-blocking resources

Tags: performance, resources, pagespeed, render-blocking

I'm trying to optimalize web for speed and wanna ask about Eliminating render-blocking CSS and JS.

by JS 'm only using async attr. - lets say, throwin' it at plugins like flexslider, lightbox.. but should I also use this with the base scripts like ?:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/.../4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
<script src="js/script.js" async></script>
```

Whenever i add async on some script and test it, that .js script won't just operate - as if not linked. What am I doing wrong? And is this enough ... ?

-by CSS - tring to impove it like this :

```html
<link rel="preload" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" media="print" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css"></noscript>
```

This cuts down the time of rendering CSS resources, but again when using it on e.g fontawesome - icons are not loaded as if link was't there...So, is this a good way of rendering CSS please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### JavaScript

When using `async` you have to ensure that load **order** does not affect your implementation.

`Async` basically says "load everything as quickly as you can, I don't care about load order".

If you haven't accounted for this then the easiest fix is to use `defer` on your JavaScript instead of `async`. This basically says "load everything after the HTML has loaded but please keep the order as some scripts depend on others".

This will be slightly slower overall but still fix the JavaScript being render blocking.

You should defer **all** scripts, except any scripts that are essential for above the fold operations (and then you should inline those scripts in a `<script>` tag in the `<header>`, obviously keep this to a minimum).

### CSS

Render blocking CSS is anything sitting in an external file that relates to content "above the fold".

To understand this fully you need to understand how the browser render things but in essence anything that is visible without scrolling ("above the fold" content) is delayed if your CSS is in an external file as it needs that information to know how to present and lay things out.

What you need to do is find all the styles that apply to your above the fold content and inline them in a `<style>` tag in the page `<header>`. Yet again this needs to be kept to a minimum so you may need to make the above the fold CSS custom rather than using bootstrap....including the whole of bootstrap inline would not be good!

Then all other styles can sit in external style sheets.

This way the second the page's HTML is downloaded it has everything it needs to layout the page without waiting for any other requests.

### Font Awesome

Ah fonts for icons. I won't go into why that is a bad practice from an accessibility and performance perspective as I have covered that numerous times before.

Instead I will simply say that for any "above the fold" icons you should instead swap them for **inline SVGs**. This is for the same reason as inlining your CSS, inline SVGs do not need a network request to render so the second the HTML is loaded your page can be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for explaining me in human lang, but practially I've tried using firstly async then defer on script flexslider.js and this somehow sabotages all javascript...And e.g boostrap.js should not be defered right ? But i don't understand why it behaves as if commented out when i use async on these -> bootstrap.js and script.js (custom).

As for Font Awesome..I understand and will replace 'em.

Comment: Look at the console, you will see an error or a warning. I tried to explain but basically you `script.js` is loading before `bootstrap.mis.js`, if you are using any of the bootstrap.min.js code in your script.js then it will fail. You can also see this in the network tab. That is why I suggested `defer` as that keeps the load order the same. Start by deferring every script on the page and then you will see if there is any functionality needed for above the fold content to work. Just reread my answer a couple of times as it takes a little while to get it but once you understand it is easy.

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion, have no way of testing atm but try putting 'async' before the source attribute. also, try adding a copied line with the attribute defer instead of async for wider browser support.

Comment: Tried to put async before src. its the same ... script just behaves as if commented out...
And you mean i should create copy for every script tag with defer ? ...i doubt that's the way it should be done.