# How to Eliminate render-blocking resources in react js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagespeed-insights

In my react app after deploy I check it for speed in PageSpeed Insight. And It results in looks likes this :

[image]

How to eliminate these render-blocking resources in my react app?

Comment: A `react` app with 2 versions of `jquery` doesn't seem wise.

Comment: @SamR. ohh then which one should  I remove? ```jquery-3.3.1.min.js```  or  ```jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js``` ?

Comment: Preferably both but I see you're using bootstrap so I don't really know. You should ask bootstrap professionals :)

Comment: You are looking for [`defer` or `async`, see if this answer helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64952744/2702894)